# Error:Execution failed for task. Apk build is not building apk

Tags: build.gradle

This Error occurs while building apk or when I run my app on API level below 20.
The app is working perfectly on API level 21 and above 21 also.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class**

The minimum SDK version for app is 16

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bodacioususer.hikashopfinal"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have mistakenly used two times the same volley library. It may produce error.